Not Showing my Work
I’m having trouble exporting my model with a texture into a .usdz file. I added an image texture to my object using the Base Color option in the material settings, and it looks fine in Blender. But when I export it as a .usdz file and open it, the texture doesn’t show up, and the object appears pink.
I understand that pink means the texture is missing, but I’m not sure how to fix this for .usdz exports. How can I ensure that the texture is included in the .usdz file so it displays correctly?

i found the problem, the image texture  was below the material.
Remember to put your image texture (prioritize them) above the material when you are putting the image texture.
